# JMeter - CSV Data Set Config failing to find CSV

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to load my CSV file in JMeter and I keep getting the error below. I have the file structure set as

> c:\claimstest\claimsload.jmx
>
> c:\claimstest\policies.csv

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I also attached a screenshot of the CSV Data Set Config[image]

```
2012/05/30 10:09:20 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2012/05/30 10:09:20 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Ending thread Thread Group 1-1 
2012/05/30 10:09:20 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2012/05/30 10:09:20 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Close: policies.csv 
2012/05/30 10:09:20 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*) 
2012/05/30 10:09:20 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Test has ended on host null 
2012/05/30 10:15:17 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2012/05/30 10:15:17 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2012/05/30 10:15:17 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2012/05/30 10:15:17 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2012/05/30 10:15:18 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All threads have been started 
2012/05/30 10:15:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2012/05/30 10:15:18 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: policies.csv 
2012/05/30 10:15:18 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored:  
2012/05/30 10:15:18 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file header line
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.reserveFile(FileServer.java:275)
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.iterationStart(CSVDataSet.java:132)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:387)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:379)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:144)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:200)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:162)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:108)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:75)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\claimstest (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.createBufferedReader(FileServer.java:341)
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:318)
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:302)
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.reserveFile(FileServer.java:273)
    ... 10 more

2012/05/30 10:15:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2012/05/30 10:15:18 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Ending thread Thread Group 1-1 
2012/05/30 10:15:18 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2012/05/30 10:15:18 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Close: policies.csv 
2012/05/30 10:15:18 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*) 
2012/05/30 10:15:18 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Test has ended on host null
```

Comment: Are you running on a Windows Vista or Windows 7? Have you started JMeter as Admin?

Comment: Windows XP. I found out my issue. I had an errant CSV Data Set Config in the depths of my Recording Controller. Dont know how that got there. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting such a error please try launching the apache J-meter with admin rights.
You just need to say "Run as administrator" & it works, It accept the csv path provided in the bin directory or anywhere in the system. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You use **CSV Data Set Config** with empty **Filename** ("").
JMeter try read CSV file from path `{current directory} + "" = "C:\claimstest"`.
But "`C:\claimstest`" is directory.

JMeter write error:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\claimstest (Access is denied)

Use `Ctrl+F` and find "`CSV`".
You find **CSV Data Set Config** with empty **Filename**, remove it.