# Jmeter doesn't accept csv input file

Tags: csv, input, jmeter

I keep getting this exception when I want to use 
*CSV Data Set Config*:

[csv config screen http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/RiFs0s.jpg](http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/RiFs0s.jpg)

The file data2.txt contains only one column:

```
num
19000716285
1148227951
2413658651
```

I have tried everything one could imagine but with no effect.

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file header line**

**Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\aaa (Access is denied)**

```
2012/11/05 09:56:21 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file header line
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.reserveFile(FileServer.java:282)
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.iterationStart(CSVDataSet.java:132)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:410)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:402)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:154)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:211)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:172)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:211)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:172)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:108)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:220)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:172)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:108)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:86)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\aaa (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.createBufferedReader(FileServer.java:398)
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:325)
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.readLine(FileServer.java:309)
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.reserveFile(FileServer.java:280)
    ... 15 more
```

**EDIT** now that I completely deleted the CSV Data Set Config node, I'm still getting the exception...

Comment: Does exception still contain "at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.iterationStart" after removing CSV Data Set Config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using absolute paths for csv files, specially if you are doing remote testing but be sure to create same folder structure on all servers.

I don't think the stacktrace you show is related to screenshot or csv data set config you show.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will be having another CSV data set config element at the depth of your recording controller or some place else. Remove that and give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT now that I completely deleted the CSV Data Set Config node, I'm still getting the exception...

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31204662/5077415

Use `Ctrl+F` + `CSV` and find another `CSV Data Set Config` node with empty `Filename`. Remove this empty `CSV Data Set Config` node.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions issue. If you are using a Windows OS, click on the D drive and go to Properties -> Security and Edit. Use the Add button and type your name then click the Check Names button and hopefully your name will pop up. Click Ok and give yourself full control.

Also do this with the JMeter folder and the Excel folder under Program files. If you still have permission issues see the System Administrator.